# Python nested 'while' loop not executing properly

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm new to Python. I came up with a simple program to test some of the tools I've learned. It works for the most part, except for one of my nested 'while' loops. Below is my code. The part that doesn't work is when I enter "manual" in my work function and it's "raining". I intended for it to print rainedOut then go back to the raw_input. Only once it's raining 3 times (i.e., after looping back to the raw_input 3 times and it being rainedOut) should it print "You should probably just give up now." and exit the function. However, what it does, is on the first go, it prints out rainedOut 3 times in a row and then ends the function automatically. Can anyone help me with the error in my code?

```
import time
import sys

done = "I'm tired of you. Goodbye."
rainedOut = "Sorry, rain foiled your plans :("
dontUnderstand = "I'm sorry, I don't understand."

def good_weather():
    """Imagine a world where every 5 seconds it rains (good_weather = False),
    then is sunny again (good_weather = True). This function should return
    whether good_weather is True or False at the time it's called.
    """
    seconds = time.time()
    seconds %= 10

    if seconds <= 5:
        good_weather = True
        return good_weather
    else:
        good_weather = False
        return good_weather

def start():
    entries = 0

    while entries < 4:
        choice = raw_input("Hello! What do you want to do right now? Options: 1) Sleep, 2) Work, 3) Enjoy the great outdoors: ")

        if choice == "1":
            print "We are such stuff as dreams are made on, and our little life is rounded with a sleep. - Shakespeare, The Tempest"
        elif choice == "2":
            work()
        elif choice == "3":
            outdoors()
        else:
            print dontUnderstand
            entries += 1
    print done

def work():
    entries = 0
    entries2 = 0

    while entries < 4:
        choice = raw_input("Would you prefer sedentary office work or manual labor in the elements?: ")

        if "office" in choice:
            print "The brain is a wonderful organ; it starts working the moment you get up in the morning and does not stop until you get into the office. -Robert Frost"
        elif "manual" in choice:
            sunny = good_weather()
            if sunny == True:
                print "A hand that's dirty with honest labor is fit to shake with any neighbor. -Proverb"
            else:
                while entries2 < 3:
                    print rainedOut
                entries2 += 1
                print "You should probably just give up now."
                sys.exit()
        else:
            print dontUnderstand
            entries += 1
    print done
    sys.exit()

def outdoors():
    sunny = good_weather()
    if sunny == True:
        print "Adopt the pose of nature; her secret is patience. -Ralph Waldo Emerson"
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print rainedOut
        start() # go back to start

start()
```

Comment: Never use `sys.exit()` to exit a loop, or function. Just `return` from the function. As to why you shouldn't, see numerous questions here. If that requires you to augment your function to `return True/False` status, or some more complicated object/None, then augment it.

Comment: You should use `break` to exit from within a loop, `return` or `return <exit-value/object>` to return from a function, and you can shortcut breaking from a loop inside a function with a `return` (as long as you know what the return value will be). Do not use `sys.exit()` as some nuclear shotgun to escape all control-flow constructs! (Teardown, memory-leaks, housekeeping, message logging, GUI threads, persistent storage... just some of many reasons why it's a terrible habit. Also, it will screw up unit-tests/ Test-Driven Design)

Comment: There is also no point in assigning a value to a variable and then immediately returning it. You're doing it at least twice (in `good_weather`). Use `return True` and `return False` instead.

Comment: @ReutSharabani: in fact those six lines can all be replaced with `return (seconds <= 5)`.

Comment: Or the entire function with `return (time.time() % 10) <= 5`

Comment: *"This function should return whether good_weather is True or False"* That's just a spec of how the function should behave. It's not requiring you to declare a local variable `good_weather` (within a function also called `good_weather()`) and assign to the variable.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice! I cleaned it up a bit more according to your suggestions and went over to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98095/trying-to-exit-out-of-the-program-after-certain-print-statements-without-using-s) to make it even better. I really appreciate your time and explanations! It's invaluable as I'm starting to learn.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this part:

```
else:
    while entries2 < 3:
        print rainedOut
    entries2 += 1
    print "You should probably just give up now."
    sys.exit()
```

To be more like this:

```
if entries2 < 3:
    print rainedOut
    entries2 += 1
    continue # restart loop (optional)
else:
    print "You should probably just give up now."
    sys.exit()
```

You're confusing the `while` (loop) and `if` (test) functionality.

Comment: You should point out to OP that the entire `if...elif...else` ladder exists inside a while-loop. The responsibility for incrementing/updating the loop-variable should be reduced to one (or very few) points in that loop. OP's undisciplined splattergun use of `sys.exit()` to break from loops/return from functions is a bad coding habit they need to stop immediately.

Comment: While I strongly agree, this is more for "Code Review" than "Stack Overflow". I've concentrated on his problem. There are more problems in the code. We can discuss them in the question's comments.

Comment: It works! You're right; thank you. I got confused because I tried to replicate a similar functionality earlier on in the work() function (i.e., while entries < 4...) Do I need to change that one from 'while' to 'if' as well?

Comment: If there are any comments about the code otherwise -- e.g., what to do instead of sys.extit() -- I'm all ears. I'm also new to SO, so I'm not sure if this is the proper venue?

Comment: @mmrtre18: see my comments above, also read good code examples here and at CodeReview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Probably not, assuming you want it to happen multiple times. Your code could probably use a post in `code review` site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/